# JountJS - Creating FSM Dynamically through PHP

Tags: fsm, state-diagram, jointjs

I'm using [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/) for creating state diagram.
I am creating FSM Dynamically through PHP. is there any way to lay the states automatically apart from each other without specifying vertices.Also the link should be made curvy without specificity x n y.

I'm working on a "Reservation Table Analyzer algorithm" with PHP, bootstrap n jQuery.
I need state diagram for this algo output. I've done everything. Its working fine but states 
are scattered n doesn't look good. even links are not appearing proper.

I need some way to place these states auto arranged without specifying vertices (x, y).
As handling their x and y in algorithm iteration is difficult.
Please take a look at demo here. http://www.figmentsol.com/rtanalyzer/
Use following data for test
Time slices:4
Add 3 resources
Resource1 : 1001
Resource2 : 0100
Resource3 : 0010
Click start to see result!

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the joint.layout.DirectedGraph.js plugin that can be found on the JointJS download page: http://jointjs.com/download  (at the bottom).

Then just call joint.layout.DirectedGraph.layout(graph, { setLinkVertices: true }).

Comment: Full discussion can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jointjs/fsm$20dynamically/jointjs/LDo5mk7q6WA/SZACr_dNSqcJ